# integrate SonarQube with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, integration, sonarqube-scan

im trying to integrate SonarQube with jenkins but im facing some errors

This is my analysis properties

```
sonar.projectBaseDir=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sonarqube
sonar.language=Java
#sonar.login=
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=.
sonar.verbose=true
sonar.projectKey=sonarqube
sonar.host.url=http://x.xxx.xx.xxx:9000/
sonar.projectName=sonarqube
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.project.settings=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sonarqube/sonarqube-scanner/sonar-project.properties
sonar.analysis.mode=publish
sonar.buildbreaker.skip=true
```

It shows me this error msg

```
08:02:22.935 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
08:02:22.961 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
08:02:22.962 DEBUG: Download: http://x.xxx.xx.xxx:9000/batch/index
08:02:27.994 ERROR: SonarQube server [http://x.xxx.xx.xxx:9000/] can not be reached
08:02:27.994 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
08:02:27.994 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
08:02:27.994 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
08:02:27.995 INFO: Total time: 5.588s
08:02:28.020 INFO: Final Memory: 3M/56M
08:02:28.020 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
08:02:28.020 ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis
```

is there any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: Looks like a proxy or firewall problem

Comment: It is worth checking whether you can reach SonarQube server from your jenkins server. Please check the connectivity. Could you please tell where you have hosted SonarQube ?